# Why is this function not having the intended behavior on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, dom, responsive-design

I have a function that I'm using to make a bunch of sibling `div`s have the same height. When the DOM is ready, I define it, call it, and then set it to be called whenever the `window` is `resiz`ed.

```
jQuery(function($){
    function rescaleStuff ( )
    {
        $('.children-have-equal-height').each(function(){
            var children = $(this).children();
            var numChildren = children.length;
            if (numChildren > 1) 
            {
                var firstChild = children.first();
                var maxHeight = firstChild.height();
                firstChild.siblings().each(function() { 
                    var thisHeight = $(this).height(); 
                    if (thisHeight > maxHeight) 
                        maxHeight = thisHeight;
                });
                children.height(maxHeight);
            }
        });
    }

    rescaleStuff();

    $(window).resize(function()
    { 
         rescaleStuff();
    });
});
```

The function `rescaleStuff` is working awesomely when it is invoked by the resizing of the `window`, but it is **not** working correctly when the page loads. For some reason, it is calculating the heights as smaller than the actual heights. Why is that?

Also, it is possible to make my procedure any more compact, elegant, readable, efficient, clever and maintainable? I didn't think so. ;)

Comment: This can also be accomplished via [FlexBox](http://osvaldas.info/flexbox-based-responsive-equal-height-blocks-with-javascript-fallback) in CSS, since you were asking for efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$( window ).load(function() {
 ....
});
```

If you have to calculate widths/heights, positions... ready() method is not sufficient. You have to wait until whole content (with images) is loaded, since content affect heights and widths.

Comment: Ah, I see. I did have images inside the `div`s that were to be resized.